# How do I set up a Paypal sandox account

Tags: paypal-sandbox

The sandbox account i have been using for the past 2 years has now disappeared and despite searching for a way to create another sandbox account it is beyond me.

Can anyone let me know how I can set up a sandbox account (I am in Australia).

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

These are pretty good instructions that assisted me with the same issue...

http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3725/how-to-create-a-sandbox-account-in-paypal

From the article...

1. Go to https://paypal.com and click signup.
2. Create an account with your details. You don't need to enter bank/card details when you want only a test account.
3. Now go to https://developer.paypal.com and login with you existing PayPal account

To get your test API key

1. Go to Applications > sandbox accounts.
2. Here you can see one account which was created by PayPal. But to create a working sandbox account to test some payment method you need to create business (merchant account).
3. To create a new sandbox account click on "Create Account" in sandbox accounts tab
4. Select account type as Business (merchant account). See the image below.
5. Give email, password and name. You need this details to check your order details.
6. leave PayPal balance as blank. Do not add any amount over there.
7. Next select any credit card type and press create account button

Same way you can create a buyer account also. Note that here you have to select Personal (buyer account) option. Once you create a buyer account go to profile then funding, here you can see you card details. You can use these details to test a purchase in your website.

To see your API credentials you can go to sandbox accounts > click on you email address > profile > API credentials. This is the API key that we have to save it in our website.

If you want to see your buyer card details, go to your buyer account > profile > funding.

Once you test your payment with your website, to see your order details in PayPal click on sandbox site link under the merchant account. Here login with your merchant username and password. Click on "All account activity" link.

Comment: Can you copy some of the important content here, in case the link disappears someday?

Comment: @user814064: Copied. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the PayPal sandbox reimplementation fiasco earlier this year, you have to use a computer located in the USA. I'm located where you are too, but fortunately I can RDP into our server in San Francisco and do it all from there.